# Cannot update document in PyMongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I have code in Python/PyMongo like ( code should simulate inner join and all documents from second collection to put (nest inside) in list and add to first appropriate document in Mongo). Idea is to load two collections and pass two fields ( name of fields for connection ) and all documents from second collection with same attribute like in first put in list and add to appropriate document  in first collection .

**(For example in first collection I have documents with fileds "country","population" and in second I have "country" and "car factories" and I want to put ( denormalize ) first collection list of all factories for appropriate country)**

```
    for f in first_collection_records:
        temp=[]
        id=f['_id']
        second_collection_records.rewind()
        for s in second_collection_records:
            if f[field_one]==s[field_two]:
                temp.append(s)
        f[self.__second_collection_name__]=temp
        first_collection_records.update({"_id":id}, f, safe=True)
```

but I got error 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'update'. What I done wrong ?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want to achieve? What kind of things do you want to update? What do you mean by .update({"_id":id}, f, safe=True)?

Comment: @EwyynTomato I added new comment, can you please help me now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`first_collection_records` is a `pymongo.cursor.Cursor` object. It's the result you get when you call `db.first_collection.find()`. You need to call `update` on your original `collection` object:

```
# assuming your query looked something like this
first_collection_records = db.first_collection.find()

# your code here....

# your last line should reference the collection object to do the update
db.first_collection.update({"_id":id}, f, safe=True)
```